# A puzzle involving independence of two random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence, covariance

First, consider sampling an $n$-bit string $x \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$ uniformly at random. Let $x_i$ be the $i^{\text{th}}$ bit of $x$.

Now, generate two output strings.

For each string:

$1$. First, choose a position $m \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ uniformly at random.

$2$. Then, for some fixed $k = \mathcal{O}(\log n)$, choose $k$ positions uniformly at random excluding the $m^{\text{th}}$ position.

Note that there are ${n-1}\choose{k}$ possible choices of $k$ positions, excluding the $m^{\text{th}}$ position, and by uniformly at random, I mean choosing any position with probability $\frac{1}{{n-1}\choose{k}}$.

$3$. Then, fill the $m^{\text{th}}$ position with a bit obtained by tossing a biased coin (that gives $0$ with probability $1/4$ and $1$ with probability $3/4$).

$4$. Then, fill the $k$ positions, that we have chosen, with a $k$ bit string $\{0, 1\}^{k}$ chosen uniformly at random.

$5$. Finally, fill the remaining $n - k - 1$ positions with the corresponding bits the string $x$ has in those positions.

Let $Y_1, Y_2$ be the two random variables corresponding to the two strings. Note that each of these output strings overlap with $x$ on at least $n- k - 1$ positions.

Here's what I couldn't prove. Are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ independent? If not, are they at least uncorrelated (that is, the covariance is $0$)? You can assume $n$ to be sufficiently large.

I have an intuition that they must be independent --- since, even if we know one of them, as the procedure is very "random," I don't see any way in which I can get any information about the other.

Comment: What is the covariance of two bit string–valued random variables? Are you interpreting the bit strings as integers?

Comment: Yes, let's say I interpret them as integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are definitely not independent, and appear likely to be correlated.  Let $Y_1 = y_1y_2 \cdots y_n$ and $Z_1 = z_1z_2 \cdots z_n$ be the two strings.  If they were independent, we would have $P(y_1 = z_1) = \frac 12$.  However, $P(y_1 = x_1)$ is at least $\frac{n-k-1}{n} = 1-\frac{k+1}{n}$ (the probability the first bit isn't chosen in the randomization procedure) and similarly $P(z_1=x_1) \ge 1-\frac{k+1}{n}$.  Since the randomization procedure is done independently, the probability the first bit is not chosen either time is $(1-\frac{k+1}{n})^2$ and hence $$P(y_1=z_1) \ge P(y_1=x_1,z_1=x_1) \ge \left(1-\frac{k+1}{n}\right)^2.$$  Since $k = \mathcal O(\log n)$, for $n$ large this tends to $1$ and in particular is greater than $\frac 12$, so we conclude $Y_1$ and $Z_1$ are not independent.

Comment: Why are they correlated again?

Comment: They are correlated because each bit is correlated.

Comment: Sanity check. $k= n - log(n)$, instead of $logn$, would we then have that the random variables are uncorrelated? The probability you calculated in the end then tends to $0$.

Comment: No, even then I think they would still be correlated.  The probability the bits are equal if one of them is selected randomly is $\frac 12$, so the total probability the bits are equal is $\frac 12$ plus the probability neither is selected in the randomization probability, and hence always greater than $\frac 12$.

Comment: Does $\Pr(y_1y_2 = z_1z_2) = \Pr(y_1=z_1) \Pr(y_2 = z_2)$? Can we at least say $\Pr(y_1y_2 = z_1z_2) \leq \Pr(y_1=z_1) \Pr(y_2 = z_2)$? In other words, are the different bits independent?

Answer (score 1):

They don't appear to be independent. If they were independent, then the distribution of the Hamming weight of $Y_1$ conditioned on $Y_2$ would simply be the distribution of the Hamming weight of $Y_1$, which is a binomial distribution with mean $\frac n2$ and variance $\frac n4$; however, under this construction, the Hamming weight of $Y_1$ is constrained to be within $O(\log n)$ of the Hamming weight of $Y_2$, which bounds the variance by $O(\log^2 n)$ even if the mean happens to be correct.

Comment: Might you elaborate on why we get the binomial distribution and how you got the bound of $O(\log^{2} n)$ on the variance?